# return array element if it exists, otherwise null

Tags: php

Given is an array `$array` and a key `$key`.  If the array has the key, then I want to return the value, otherwise null. Is there a better way in PHP7 now, then doing it like that:

```
return (empty($array[$key])) ? null : $array[$key];
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the *question title*, there indeed a [null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) introduced in PHP7:

```
return $array[$key] ?? null;
```

which is a shorthand for

```
return (isset($array[$key])) ? $array[$key] : null;
```

however, in your *code* you are using `empty()` which is different from isset() and for this code there is no shorthand in PHP.

with empty(), your code will also return null if `$array[$key]` exists but contains an empty-like value, like `false`, 0, empty array and such